# How to check the type of a Firestore server timestamp in ClojureScript?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, clojurescript

When I fetch a document from Firestore with a timestamp, the timestamp serializes as `[Object]`, so I need to transform these field values to datetime instants. To do this, I need to be able to walk the document data and convert timestamps.

How do I check if the type of these fields match the Firestore timestamp type without knowing ahead of time what the field names will be?

Answer (score 0):

## Solved:

```
(ns some.namespace
  (:require ["@google-cloud/firestore" :as firestore]
            [clojure.walk :as walk]))

(def Timestamp (.-Timestamp firestore))

(defn fire->date [fire-date]
  (.toDate fire-date))

(defn fire->clj [doc]
  (walk/postwalk
    (fn [x]
      (cond
        (= (type x) Timestamp) (fire->date x)
        :default x))
    doc))
```